# Checkboxes values inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dynamic number of questions that the user can check or not

[image]

All of those questions have an ID as well but they don't have a preset variable that states "true" or "false" whether they are checked.

I want to have at all time a variable that will have, the question ID and it state, how should I do that ?

For the moment I can get the question ID and set it to true :

[image]

But I can't remove the true value once it's set, basically, I want the same variable to be initialized with all the questions ID I have and set to default = false, once the user check the checkbox the value becomes true if he unchecks false, etc...

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-grid" ng-repeat="question in autoQuestions" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="row" style="align-items: center;">
    <div class="cell colspan6" style="text-align: end; padding-right: 10%">{{question.libelle}}</div>
    <label class="input-control checkbox cell colspan6">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkSelected(question.code)" ng-click="addSelected(question.code)">
      <span class="check"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
scope.selectedQuestions = [];
scope.addSelected = function (code) {
  var idx = scope.selectedQuestions.indexOf(code);
  if (scope.selectedQuestions.indexOf(code) == -1) {
    scope.selectedQuestions.push({ code: code, answer: true });
    console.log(scope.selectedQuestions);
    if (scope.selectedQuestions.length == scope.questionsLength) {
      scope.enableAutoBtn = true;
    }
  } else {
    scope.selectedQuestions.splice(idx, 1);
    scope.enableAutoBtn = false;
    console.log(scope.selectedQuestions);
  }
};

scope.checkSelected = function (code) {
  var idx = scope.selectedQuestions.indexOf(code);
  return idx > -1;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="question.answer" />`? All those event handlers and array manipulation seems unnecessary

Comment: The fact is that my array doesn't have the answer property at the start, maybe it's a backend error from me but the array with questions shouldn't contain the answer with the model I've been given, the boolean that state if an answer is true or false is in a separated DTO

Comment: This is JavaScript. The `answer` property will be created on the fly once a question is checked.